# count the 3 different values ​that a column can take

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to count the 3 different values ​​that a column in a table can take, in a single SELECT. What am I doing wrong?

```
with cls.getDictCursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT s.matricola,r.lingua, r.livello,COUNT (CASE WHEN tipoProva=0 THAN 1) AS testInformatizzato,\
        COUNT (CASE WHEN tipoProva=1 THAN 1) AS provaScritta,\
        COUNT (CASE WHEN tipoProva=2 THAN 1) AS provaOrale \
        FROM risultatoprovacla AS r \
            JOIN studentecla AS s ON s.id = r.id_risultatocladistu_studentecla \
        WHERE s.matricola ILIKE %s \
        GROUP BY s.matricola,r.lingua,r.livello\
        ORDER BY r.lingua;", (matricola,))
```

I am using a postgresql table where the column named "tipoprova" is an integer

Comment: What is the result of the code you showed us, and what result were you expecting instead? Can you simplify the code and provide some sample data so that we have a [mcve] to refer to for answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for filtered aggregation:

```
SELECT s.matricola,r.lingua, r.livello,
       COUNT(*) filter (where tipoProva=0) AS testInformatizzato,
       COUNT(*) filter (where tipoProva=1) AS provaScritta,
       COUNT(*) filter (where tipoProva=2) AS provaOrale 
FROM risultatoprovacla AS r 
  JOIN studentecla AS s ON s.id = r.id_risultatocladistu_studentecla 
WHERE s.matricola ILIKE %s 
GROUP BY s.matricola,r.lingua,r.livello
ORDER BY r.lingua;
```

---

Your query is wrong, because you have the wrong syntax for the CASE expression. It needs to be `THEN` not `THAN` and it also needs to be ended with `END`, e.g.:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN tipoProva=1 THEN 1 END) AS provaScritta
```

would be the correct syntax